# Quarkus : com.google.protobuf-protoc-linux-x86_64-exe: 1: cannot open !--: No such file

Tags: java, grpc, quarkus, proto, graalvm

Quarkus maven install command doesn't work after platform version 2.6.3.Final.

pom.xml ;

```
<properties>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.7.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
</properties>
```

Everything is normal in version 2.6.3.Final, but for versions after 2.7.**, even if it is exist in the /target,  it's getting an error as follows;

```
com.google.protobuf-protoc-linux-x86_64-exe: 1: cannot open !--: No such file
```

### [image]

```
ROG-PC:/Projects/$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< microservice:configurator >------------
[INFO] Building Configurator Microservice 1.0.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ configurator ---
[INFO] Deleting /Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ configurator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.4.Final:generate-code (default) @ configurator ---
/Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/target/com.google.protobuf-protoc-linux-x86_64-exe: 1: cannot open !--: No such file
/Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/target/com.google.protobuf-protoc-linux-x86_64-exe: 3: Copyright: not found
/Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/target/com.google.protobuf-protoc-linux-x86_64-exe: 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.602 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-17T17:30:45+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.7.4.Final:generate-code (default) on project configurator: 
Quarkus code generation phase has failed: InvocationTargetException: Failed to generate Java classes from proto files:
 [/Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/src/main/proto/customer_configuration.proto] to
 /Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/target/generated-sources/grpc with command /Projects/Source/configurator-microservice/target/com.google.protobuf-protoc-linux-x86_64-exe
```

mvn version;

```
ROG-PC:/Projects/$ mvnq -v
   Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
   Maven home: /Projects/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.4
   Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-21.3.0
   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
   OS name: "linux", version: "5.13.0-19-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**NOTE: This error occurs only if there are .proto files in the project.**

All Quarkus Dependencies added to pom.xml.

I don't know what is difference between quarkus platform version 2.6.3 and 2.7.** and why this getting this error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please open an issue in our tracker with a small reproducer: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/24393